# Modelling a spring interpolation

Tags: python, computational-physics, numerical-modelling, modeling

I have parameters $T$ for tension, $b$ for bounciness and $P_t$ for target value that should be approached as t goes to infinity.

Currently I have written an equation like so:

$\ddot{f}(t)=\frac{T(P_t-f(t))-\ddot{f}(t)}{b}$

Which is taken from code that I have written. However, while the code works, this equation does not get me a function that is similar to the results shown by my code. Where have I gone wrong into translating the python code into a mathematical function of time?

This is my code:

```py
g_velocity = 0.0

# note: fr = from, from is just a taken keyword in python

def lerp(fr, to, amount):
    return fr + (amount * (to - fr))

def spring_interp(fr, to, bounciness, tension):
    global g_velocity
    g_velocity = lerp(g_velocity, (to - fr) * tension, 1.0 / bounciness)
    return fr + g_velocity

# usage (example values):
# the value will then oscillate, dampened over time and approach the target_value

value = 1.0
target_value = 8.0
while True:
    value = spring_interp(value, target_value, 8.0, 0.4)
    print(value)
```

Edit:
Yes, the correct function I am trying to solve would be
$\ddot{f}(t)=\frac{T(P_t-f(t))-\dot{f}(t)}{b}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to solve the initial value problem
$$
\ddot{f}(t) = \frac{T (P_t - f(t))}{1 + b}\\
f(0) = v_0\\
\dot{f}(0) = g_0
$$
Note that I re-arranged your equation by collecting all the $\ddot{f}(t)$ terms to the left-hand side.
This has the solution
$$
f(t) = P_t + (v_0-P_t) \cos\left(t \sqrt{\frac{T}{\sqrt{1+b}}}\right)
+ \frac{g_0}{T} \sqrt{(b+1) T} \sin\left(t \sqrt{\frac{T}{1+b}}\right)
$$
This solution does not damp such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t) = P_t$, but instead oscillates indefinitely.

I suspect the ODE problem you might have been expecting to solve is
$$
\ddot{f}(t) = \frac{T(P_t - f(t)) - \dot{f}(t)}{b}\\
f(0) = v_0\\
\dot{f}(0) = g_0
$$
This system does have the property that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t) = P_t$

Here's a numerical solution for this second system I obtained using scipy's solve_ivp:
[image]

And here's the first 100 iterations of your code:

[image]

I think you're numerical implementation might be a forward Euler method with $\Delta t = 1$?